# Unable to use catch/3 for tcp_connect in prolog

Tags: try-catch, windows-10, swi-prolog

I want to check whether a server is listening or not and for that I use the code shown below.

```
:- use_module(library(socket)).

goal(IP,Port,Sock):-
    tcp_socket(Sock),
    tcp_connect(Sock,IP:Port).

main(IP,Port):-
    catch(goal(IP,Port,Sock),error(X,Y),writeln('Error')).
```

I call the main part from the console. I have tried to use **catch/3** to catch the error but my code always get stuck and i get operating system error **'swipl. exe has stopped working'** which forces me to close the prolog console. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I tried this in Debian, using the latest development version of SWI, and it works exactly as expected. Are you also using the latest version of SWI-Prolog?

Comment: @mat Thanks. It worked with the latest development release. I was using the stable release version 7.2.3.

Comment: Great! Please post this as an answer and accept it, to mark this question as closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. I was using stable release 7.2.3. Using the development release 7.3.2 resolved my problem.